# Как в PHP слить 2 массива с одинаковыми значениями, и перезаписать их?

Tags: php, массивы

Как в PHP слить 2 массива с одинаковыми значениями, и перезаписать их?

Пример:

Первый массив

```
Array
(
[89] => Array
    (
        [NAME] => "Имя1"
        [ELEMENTS] => Array
            (
                [2702] => "Значение1"
                [2703] => "Значение2"
                [2704] => "Значение3"
            )

    )

[90] => Array
    (
        [NAME] => "Имя2"
        [ELEMENTS] => Array
            (
                [2694] => "Значение1"
                [2695] => "Значение2"
            )

    )
)
```

Второй массив

```
Array
(
[100] => Array
    (
        [NAME] => "Имя1"
        [ELEMENTS] => Array
            (
                [2755] => "Значение1"
                [2756] => "Значение2"
            )

    )

[101] => Array
    (
        [NAME] => "Имя2"
        [ELEMENTS] => Array
            (
                [2800] => "Значение1"
                [2801] => "Значение2"
            )

    )
)
```

Как их слить так, чтобы получился такой массив, то есть значения из второго массива перезаписали одинаковые значения первого:

```
Array
(
[100] => Array
    (
        [NAME] => "Имя1"
        [ELEMENTS] => Array
            (
                [2755] => "Значение1"
                [2756] => "Значение2"
                [2704] => "Значение3"
            )

    )

[101] => Array
    (
        [NAME] => "Имя2"
        [ELEMENTS] => Array
            (
                [2800] => "Значение1"
                [2801] => "Значение2"
            )

    )
)
```

Comment: `array_merge_recursive()` ?

Comment: к сожалению, он сливает их и не заменяет ничего кроме ключей на 0,1..

Comment: да, ключи он числовые сбрасывать должен. а какой алгоритм слияния у вас. у вас для Имя1 для значений разные id, по какому принципу сливать то хотите?

Comment: Есть 2 массива. 1-ый стандартные значения, 2-ой новые. 3-ий массив - это стандартные+новые. То есть всё что во 2-ом массиве заменяет то что есть с таким же значением в первом. Ключи это Id-шники

Answer (score 1):

Обычно массивы сливают не по значениям, а по ключам. 
Для такой структуры массивов (`$adata`, `$bdata`) можно решить задачу, например, следующим образом.

```
$result = [];
foreach($adata as $a) {
    foreach ($bdata as $k => $b) {
        if ($a['NAME'] != $b['NAME']) continue;

        $fa = array_flip($a['ELEMENTS']);
        $fb = array_flip($b['ELEMENTS']);
        $el = array_flip(array_merge($fa, $fb));

        $result[$k] = ['NAME' => $a['NAME'], 'ELEMENTS' => $el];
    }
}
```